# Using iterator in a cost distance analysis model with multiple destinations

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator, cost-path

I am building a cost distance model to find three different paths. Each has his own start and end point. So there are three start points with each an end point belonging to it. I want to use an iterator and variable inputs:

[image]

The iterator works now and creates three different outputs with each start point. The problem is that I cannot connect them with the end points. I can always only put end point 1 into the model and every start point end at end point one. But start point two and three should end on their own end point.

I tried to write Endpoint_%Value% but he does not accept it. I couldnt get it to run yet. Can anyone help?

I now did it like you said and get this:

[image]

That means that it is still not working correctly and although I put OBJECTID as destination field it connects the startpoint to all three destination points..

I now tried:
As I write destination_%Value% in the Cost path input field with stable inputs it works and I get the output I want!! 
But as I'm doing it with variables he does not accept this input... I dont understand why because it is exactly the same only written somewhere else...

Answer (score 1):

Just you should pay attention to one thing **(GroupField of Iterator = DestinationField of cost path)**.

So in your case (e.g define the ID of the point)

In this example (field is destination):

The model looks like:

[image]

The iteration looks like:

[image]

Cost distance (output distcane raster e.g Cost_%Value%):

[image]

Cost Path (output raster e.g CostPat_%Value%):

[image]

The result:

[image]

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: and how did you create the connection between feature out and cost path?

Comment: @Loki so your problem now is how to connect the feature_out with cost path? just connect it as shown in my answer

Comment: Did you connect it as destination input? That would be wrong in my case. Because these are only the start points and not the end points. The problem is how to connect the end points with variables. It should be endpoint_%Value% and that works in a model with stale inputs (colored) but not in the variable model (white). Do you understand?

Comment: the other solution by making another submodel and main model, to insert new iterator for the end_points and connect them together with cost path and the output from submodel.

Comment: Yes I already thought about that. Maybe I will have to try it then .

Comment: I still couldnt make it work until now. I thought about your solution. What does your output look like? Because if you use the same points as start an destination point the cost path must be zero/not existent?